# How to find Item Lifetime based on Item Consumption?

Tags: python, statistics, data-science

**Imagine the following problem:** 
Your friend bought a brand new car with 20 wheels and this car is driving large distances. As the car drives the car consumes tires. Every time your friend needs a new tire, he calls you to send a new tire. And of course you do that.

After 2 years you want to know what the lifetime of that particular tire actually is. But, the only thing you know is

1. That you send your friend 26 tires in the last 2 years
2. The dates you sent tires to your friend
3. His car has 20 wheels
4. His car was brand new to start with
5. All the tires were for the same car

How can we find the lifetime of this tire with only the data we have?

---

This problem is what I'm facing today. When a tier (or any other item) is replaced, the system will not track where in the machine it was replaced, only that it was replaced. For me this makes it difficult to come up with a method to find the lifetime.

Is there anyone, who can guide me in the right direction? 
Is there a sort of python library which can be used?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution that comes in mind is the average duration between the sending events.
This can only applied if you send tire for tire and not in a batch. In this case you have additonal complexity.

1. You need a list of all dates
2. Sort the list by date
3. Iterate over the list and calculate the duration between two dates following each other
4. Save the duration in another list
5. Calculate the average duration from this list

Now you have the average wheel lifetime for the whole vehicle. Multiply this duration by 20 to get the lifetime of the average tire.

Correct me if I am wrong or didnt understand the question.

Comment: Hi Lukas, Thanks for you answer. I understand your logic only that logic will not provide the lifetime, only in case T->infinite, which is not the case. I thought perhaps there is a different way of doing this, but even though it seems a quite straight forward problem, it becomes more and more complex..